# How do I use Python and PyQt4 to start a default application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I am using Python 3 and PyQt4 (and Kubuntu 12.04).

I often use QtCore.Qprocess.startDetached (QString program, QStringList arguments)
to start a program to process a file specified in the arguments.

I want a corresponding manner to start processing the specified file without specifying which program to use.
Rather I want to start the default program available, e.g. OpenOffice or LibreOffice or any other program designated 
as the default word processor for an .odt document file.

Alternatively, is there a way to ask the system which is the default program to use?

/ingemar

Comment: `xdg-open` for Linux, `start` for Windows?

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you BlaXpirit

Answer (score 3):

```
QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl('file:///home/test/test_document.odt'))
```

Alternatively, you can use the system commands `xdg-open` (Linux) and `start` (Windows).